# How to reconnect from a notification intent to a running AsyncTask on Android?

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent, android-asynctask

I'm downloading files in my app through an AsyncTask. While a download is in progress, I create a notification in the Notification Bar and display a ProgressBar on my Activity.

Now, if the user exists my app the download might be still in progress. The intent from the Notification Bar allows the user to return to my app, but if that happens my app is shown in its initial state.

How can I return to the state my app had before the user left? With my AsyncTask updating the ProgressBar?

Thanks a lot!
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For downloading/uploading files you should use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). What it does is that it keeps on running until the operation is complete and then finishes itself. Better still you can use [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Now while your download is in progress you can keep the progress stored in your service and when its tapped fire an Intent which will re-create the activity with the ProgressBar initialized to the current download progress. You will have to set the proper Intent [flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) so as not to re-create this activity if it's already present.

Better still, you can show the progress in your notification bar itself using a custom view.  Depends on what behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look into IntentService already, but I guess this isn't to do as a quick fix. :( Do you have a link to a neat tutorial. What I found so far explains how to implement such a type of a class, but not how to actually use it. I have some really weird constructs in my testing class since yesterday evening, maybe I just don't see the wood for the trees...

Comment: Really specific tutorials for Android are hard to find. I just got hints from different SO answers and the documentation. :)

Comment: thanks, I found what I was looking for in a Commonsware book - as expected. ;)
But: I cannot reconnect to the IntentService! :( The IntentService is not bound to my activity, so when I close my app and reopen it, shouldn't startService(myIntent) tell the service where my application context is?